# is there a way to print a different variable every iteration in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm making a dice rolling game for some homework and I was adding a feature so you could have as many players as you want but I've come to a problem. I want to be able to change the name of the variable it prints in every iteration. e.g guess0 then guess1 etc but I can't work out how to do it. I expect it to print the value of each variable every iteration of the for loop.

```
for dice in range(player_no):
     exec(f'guess{dice}=random.randint(1,7)')

for i in range(player_no):
    print(guess,{i})
```

I've tried looking for answers on lots of different sites but none of them seemed to fix the problem I hoped some of you could help.

Comment: You should avoid using dynamic variables, they are not necessary for this. You probably just want to use a `list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you give some example output? Also check out [ask] and [mre] if you want more tips. **Edit** Whoops, I misread the `exec` as `print`. I agree with Juanpa and c2huc2hu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the second for loop, you can try something like below:

```
for i in range(6):
    print('guess%d' % i)
```

A better way is to use the format function in Python 3:

```
for i in range(6):
    print ("guess{}".format(i))
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
player_no = 10    
for i in range(player_no):
        print("guess{}".format(i))
```

this will output:

```
guess0
guess1
guess2
guess3
guess4
guess5
guess6
guess7
guess8
guess9
```

is this what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

Use a list instead of dynamic variables. For more details see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

```
guesses = [random.randint(1, 7) for _ in range(player_no)]

for guess in guesses:
    print(guess)
```

Though if you don't need the list for anything else, don't bother.

```
for _ in range(player_no):
    guess = random.randint(1, 7)
    print(guess)
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... I'd appreciate any feedback